# Doing some counter manipulation, how do I make it so that if setCounter() has no arguments, the counter would be zero?

Tags: c++

Given the following C++ program:

```
#include "counterType.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

counterType::counterType()
{
    counter = 0;
}

counterType::counterType(int c)
{
    setCounter(c);
}

void counterType::setCounter(int ck)
{
    counter = ck;
}

int counterType::getCounter()
{
    return counter;
}

void counterType::incrementCounter()
{
    ++counter;
}

void counterType::decrementCounter()
{
    --counter;
}

void counterType::print()
{
    cout << "Counter = "<< counter << endl;
}
```

The code seems to only work when setCounter() has an argument in it. The only tests that fail are when is has no argument. So how do I check it in a way that if there is no argument, then the counter would be 0?

Comment: In this case it's pretty obvious what you are asking, but it would still have been nice if you had provided the class declaration. Or *even better* a [mcve].

Answer (score 5):

This is the perfect place for a default function argument.  Since this is a class member function that means you need to change your function declaration to be

```
void setCounter(int ck = 0);
```

To tell the compiler that if a value is not provided for `ck` that it can use `0` as the default value.  That means your function definition stays the same since it "pulls in" the default value from he declaration.

Answer (score 4):

Two approaches:

1) Supply a default argument **in the function declaration** so you can call the function without supplying it.

```
void setCounter(int ck = 0);
```

2) *Overload* the function

```
void counterType::setCounter()
{
    counter = 0;
}
```

Some software houses (particularly those where the code standard guys are Java folk) disallow the first style. A less facetious reason for not liking the first way is that the default argument value can be run-time evaluable (a member variable perhaps) and that can harm program stability.

Comment: maybe mention that the default argument goes into the declaration

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: Yes, that's really rather important!

Comment: btw thats my reason to prefer overloads, it is too easy to get confused when looking only at the definition

Answer (score 1):

For starters you can initialize the data member `counter` in the declaration of the data member within the class definition. For example

```
class counterType
{
    //...
    int counter = 0;
};
```

In this case the constructors can look like

```
counterType::counterType()
{
}

counterType::counterType(int c) : counter( c )
{
}
```

Or you could define the constructors the following way

```
counterType::counterType() : counterType( 0 ) 
{
}

counterType::counterType(int c) : counter( c )
{
}
```

The function `setCounter` can have a default argument

```
void counterType::setCounter(int ck = 0 )
{
    counter = ck;
}
```

It is better to declare the function `getCounter` within the class definition like

```
int getCounter() const;
```

because the function does not change the object itself. And define it like

```
int counterType::getCounter() const
{
    return counter;
}
```

And this function

```
void counterType::print()
{
    cout << "Counter = "<< counter << endl;
}
```

is better to declare and define like

```
std::ostream & print( std::ostream &os = std::cout ) const;
```

and define it like

```
std::ostream & print( std::ostream &os = std::cout ) const;
{
    return os << "Counter = "<< counter << endl;
}
```

It also does not change the object itself so it should be declared with the qualifier `const`.

As it seems your class has only one data member then you could define the `operator <<` for the whole class. For example

```
class counterType
{
    //...
    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const counterType &c );
};

std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const counterType &c )
{
    return os << "Counter = "<< c.counter << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that?

```
void counterType::setCounter()
{
    counter = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve is called *function overloading*: given a different list of arguments, C++ lets you define a different "version" of the same function.

```cpp
void counterType::setCounter()           // No argument in there
{
    counter = 0;
}
```